# Progress bar linking to a music button

Tags: ios, uiprogressview

In Xcode, I have set my buttons to play a music clip which will last 40 seconds. My question is how do I link up a UIProgressView to the music playing? For example, if the song is half way through, the progress bar will display that.

Comment: How are you playing the music?  AVAudioPlayer has a currentTime and duration which you could use to calculate the value to pass to UIProgressView.

Comment: Yes I am using the avaudioplayer, could you give me a short explain of linking it up to the player? I have tried but gives lots of errors?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the following defined in your class:

```
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
UIProgressView *progressView;
NSTimer *audioTimer;
```

Running it off a timer seems to work:

```
- (void)audioProgressUpdate
{
    if (audioPlayer != nil && audioPlayer.duration > 0.0)
        [progressView setProgress:(audioPlayer.currentTime / audioPlayer.duration)];
}
```

When you start the clip start the timer (this runs it every tenth of a second):

```
[audioPlayer play];
audioTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(audioProgressUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And when you stop the clip, stop the timer:

```
[audioTimer invalidate];
[audioPlayer stop];
```